# Does my marriage to an EU citizen give me unlimited freedom of movement within the EU

Tags: schengen

I am a UK national and my husband is Greek. We have been living in the UK for 15 years then for the last  year have let our house and have been travelling around europe spending a month or two in each destination before moving to the next which we hope to continue to do.
We do not want to settle and reside in any country but to continue with this nomadic lifestyle.
Now that brexit has happened am I limited to the 90 days in 180 rule or can I still travel unlimited when travelling with my EU husband?
We do not work but do have a regular income from property we let in the UK

Comment: Your freedom of movement is not unlimited but it is quite extensive. You are in any case covered by EU law *as long as you travel with your husband*. See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64168/long-stay-schengen-visa-requirement-for-spouse-of-uk-citizen?noredirect=1&lq=1 for more details on a similar situation.

Comment: You're not asking about this and I might be reading too much into your username but do note that if yours is a same-sex marriage, it has historically been a challenge to get it recognized in some member states. [A recent court case should however put an end to that](https://cadmus.eui.eu/bitstream/handle/1814/64525/LAW_2019_03.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y).